# Load data from database in _layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a web application using ASP.NET MVC 4.

I want to display the user's nickname on all of pages, so I have to load it in `_layout.cshtml`.

Please note that I'm storing user's nickname manually. (In my own database and my own tables.)

I can add user's User name by `Membership.GetUser().UserName`, but I want to load his nickname from database and show it in `_layout.cshtml`.

How to do that?

Comment: Please take a look at approach detailed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11740128/1105881).

Comment: Define "simpler". Of course you can access database inside your layour code, but that defies the idea of MVC.

Comment: I agree, but it has too much work for something simple like this :)

Comment: It seems simple only at first glance. As soon as you think about all the implications it's not so simple anymore. Besides, most part of work is already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to upon logging in, store the username in a session variable (which is done by accessing the Session object, which implements a key=value pair architecture allowing you to store and retrieve your data at will). It's a drag on performance to have to make a database call for EVERY page that loads, and a single nickname string variable in session won't take up that much space on your server.

As far as loading the variable you could use the code posted by Vahid, but I would recommend you if your site is still in its infancy to take the extra time to learn and implement Entity Framework. It is cleaner, easier and Microsoft is really pushing data connection management in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a simple solution for what you want:
write an action in a controller (mine is CommonController):

```
    public ActionResult NickName()
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnstr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, cn);
        cn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string nickName = string.Empty;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            nickName = dr["nick_Name"].ToString();
        }

        dr.close()
        return Content(nickName);
    }
```

put the below line in everywhere you want in _Layout:

```
         nickname = @{Html.RenderAction("NickName", "Common");}
```

Finished!

Thanks to @SergRogovtsev for recommending:

```
       nickname = @Html.Action("NickName", "Common")
```

**first asked:**
Are you using entity framework?
You can use partial views in _Layout either using EF or ADO. 
If you mean you can't access aspnet_membership table by using entity framework, you should ask your question in another way!

let me know more about your problem by giving some sample of your code.

Comment: No, I'm not using entity framework. I am connecting to database via `SqlConnection`s. Also I'm not trying to access `aspnet_membership` table or any asp.net tables. I said, I am storing nicknames in my own tables.

Comment: @VahidHassani have you considered performance implications of `RenderAction`?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev You'r right! The performance is not considered in my solution but it is a trade off between simplicity and performance.

Comment: You have not closed `SqlConnection` in the example. It is better to close it!

Comment: What is the difference between Html.Action and Html.RenderAction ?

Comment: Yes @MahdiGhiasi, I must close datareader ofcourse. refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used a combination of Mr_Creostoe and Vahid answers.

I am saving nickname in a session (as Mr_Cresotoe said), and if there isn't such session (for example, if user ticked *remember me* checkbox and is visiting after many time), I'll create that session using `RenderAction`. (As Vahid said).

Thank you guys!